# How to fill a global array of structures in c

Tags: c

this is the definition and declaration of the structure

```
typedef struct ST_accountsDB_t
{
    float balance;
    uint8_t primaryAccountNumber[20];
}ST_accountsDB_t;
ST_accountsDB_t accountsDB[255];
```

then I started filling it

```
    accountsDB[0].balance = 20000;
    accountsDB[0].primaryAccountNumber[20] = "1234567891234567";
    accountsDB[1].balance = 50000;
    accountsDB[1].primaryAccountNumber[20] = "9872653461728839";
    accountsDB[2].balance = 40000;
    accountsDB[2].primaryAccountNumber[20] = "6873645738467382";
    accountsDB[3].balance = 28000;
    accountsDB[3].primaryAccountNumber[20] = "3872634547838276";
    accountsDB[4].balance = 3000;
    accountsDB[4].primaryAccountNumber[20] = "1283764957873637";
    accountsDB[5].balance = 100000;
    accountsDB[5].primaryAccountNumber[20] = "3485793029384758";
    accountsDB[6].balance = 30000;
    accountsDB[6].primaryAccountNumber[20] = "8746330283748393";
```

this is the normal way to fill a string right ? why isn't it working ? am I missing something ?

Comment: There's no `primaryAccountNumber[20]`. Since the length of the array is 20, the indexes go from 0 to 19. And the elements of the array are integers, but a string becomes a pointer when you assign it.

Comment: Using `sprintf` is an option

Comment: @Barmar when I assign it as a pointer it gives me an error "expression must be a modifiable Ivalue"

Comment: You can't assign to an array. You could use `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize it when you declare it, using an initialization list.

```
ST_accountsDB_t accountsDB[255] = {
    {20000, "1234567891234567"},
    {50000, "9872653461728839"},
    ...
};
```

If you want to fill it in after declaring it, use `strcpy()` to copy strings.

```
strcpy(accountsDB[0].primaryAccountNumber, "1234567891234567");
```

Even though `uint8_t` is equivalent to `unsigned char`, it's conventional to use `char` arrays to declare strings.

```
typedef struct ST_accountsDB_t
{
    float balance;
    unsigned char primaryAccountNumber[20];
}ST_accountsDB_t;
```

Comment: uint8_t is a typedef for char

Comment: Actually it's a typedef for `unsigned char`. But if you mean for it to be a string, use `char` to indicate that. Using `uint8_t` implies that you're using it for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you initialize the variable:

```
ST_accountsDB_t accountsDB[255] = {
    {  20000.0, "1234567891234567", },
    {  50000.0, "9872653461728839", },
    {  40000.0, "6873645738467382", },
    /* ...*/ };
```

2. In the code (but not initialization) using compound literals.

```
accountsDB[x] = (ST_accountsDB_t){  40000.0, "6873645738467382", };
```

3. You cant assign arrays. You need to copy them yourself. If it is a string you need to use `strcpy` function.

```
strcpy(accountsDB[0].primaryAccountNumber,"1234567891234567");
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have told you, use an initializer list. However, when doing so also consider using *designated initializers* to make the code safer and more readable:

```
ST_accountsDB_t accountsDB[] =
{
  { .balance = 20000, .primaryAccountNumber = "1234567891234567" },
  { .balance = 50000, .primaryAccountNumber = "9872653461728839" },
  /* and so on */
};
```

You can also add a compile-time check to ensure data integrity:

```
#define ACCOUNTS_DB_SIZE 255
...
_Static_assert(sizeof accountsDB/sizeof accountsDB[0] == ACCOUNTS_DB_SIZE,
               "Wrong size: accountsDB");
```

Answer (score -1):

You want the compiler to fill-in a character array from a string. Don't make it difficult for everyone. Copy/paste/adapt is NOT the way to develop code.

```
typedef struct ST_accountsDB_t {
    float balance;
    char primaryAccountNumber[20]; // NB char, not uint8_t
} ST_accountsDB_t;

ST_accountsDB_t accountsDB[] = {
    {  20000.0, "1234567891234567", },
    {  50000.0, "9872653461728839", },
    {  40000.0, "6873645738467382", },
    {  28000.0, "3872634547838276", },
    {   3000.0, "1283764957873637", },
    { 100000.0, "3485793029384758", },
    {  30000.0, "8746330283748393", },
};
```

And, using the dimension 255 suggests you've spent the time counting... The compiler counts more accurately than most humans.

Comment: 255 is the number requested in the project

Comment: In that case `255` belongs as `#define NUM_ACCTS 255` or `const int numAccts = 255` so it can be used elsewhere without "magic numbers" sprinkled through the code... PS: It would be more 'normal' if there were 256 elements in the array numbered '0' to '255'... Just a thought...

Comment: a question please , i filled the array like you said , and i put them in a file called server.h 
then i include the file in main.c 
i get the error  LNK2005 accountsDB already defined in main.obj 
do you know why ?

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim You should avoid putting data in header files. Those are for token definitions (`#define xx..`) and function prototypes (`FILE *fopen(...`)... Put the structure declaration in a header, and the initialisation in a `.c`... If you need more than a single `.c` put a declaration of the data's name (`extern accountsDB[ ];`) in the header... All the "compilation units" (ie. the `.c` files) will know there is one and what it looks like, but only one of them actually holds the data. The link editor (last step of compiling) connects everything together.

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim Or, have you the definition of `accountsDB[ ]` in BOTH the header AND the `main.c`?? Its existence can be declared repeatedly, but its `definition` (and populating it) can only occur in one location...